# Changing Model & notifyListeners() without Provider.of()

Tags: flutter

I wonder if it's okay to change model and notifyListeners() by using model instance.

Here is the example.

```
UserModel() {
  // ... some code here ...
  updateName() {
    // ... some code here...
    notifiyListeners();
  }
}
UserModel userModel = UserModel();

// ...

Widget build(...) {
  return ChangeNotifierProvider {
    builder: (context) => userModel,
    child: MaterialApp(...)
  }
}

// ...

SomeWidget build(BuildContext context) {
  RaisedButton( child: ..., onPressed: () {
    userModel.updateName();
  }
}
```

If you see the code above, I am not using `Provider.of<UserModel>(context).updateName()`.

I just access userModel to update the model and notifyListeners();

Is this okay?

Comment: No. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's depend on the instance of your `Models`. `Provider.of` method be the syntax sugar of the way help your child widget communicate with `Models` of the parent widget. So, if you have another way to do it (for technical reason I don't know) This's okay. However, `Provider.of` be one of the most useful way until now.